# Compare queries from two distinct database systems

Tags: sql, sql-server, interface, comparison

I have two databases that are on completely different systems SAP / SQL Server. The tables themselves are of different sizes. What I'm trying to do is compare the result of a query from one of these with the result of a query from another.

If I had it all on one DB what I'm trying to do be something like

```
SELECT S.badgeNumber, M.badgeNumber 
FROM EmpTab1 S, EmpTab2 M 
WHERE S.badgeNumber = M.badgeNumber
```

That returns a nice simple table with what I want.

Is there a way to do this more elegantly than mass text comparisons of the base results of both individual queries?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: SAP is not actually a database type.  Could you be more specific as to which database the SAP data is located on?

Comment: i laughed and then felt old. yes this is a old h.r. db system but its not 25 years old. it's closer to 10 i think.

Comment: Well shoot, Microsoft makes is relatively easy to 'proxy' other MS SQL databases.  Two major brands like Oracle and MS SQL might even support each other, but you're probably looking at third party integration with an unsupported DB.